# Convenience init vs self initialization

Tags: swift, class, initialization

Why would you use a convenience init instead of just setting a default value to the class property?

Comment: From https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html: *"Create convenience initializers whenever a shortcut to a common initialization pattern will save time or make initialization of the class clearer in intent."*. Can you elaborate what *your* alternative would be?

Answer (score 2):

Convenience initializers can be used for all kinds of things that have nothing to do with default values. They can provide data conversions, or many other features. In this example, a convenience initializer allows you to pass a Float to something that requires an Int.

```
import Foundation

class X {
    let value: Int
    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }

    convenience init(rounding float: Float) {
        self.init(value: Int(round(float)))
    }
}
```

Of course this could also be written as a designated (non-convenience) initializer, but delegating to a small number of designated initializers makes subclassing much simpler and can reduce code duplication (thus "convenience").

Answer (score 0):

You do not always provide a default value to a class property, sometimes you create a class with properties and method and all the value of the property you might get it later when you create an instance of that class. For that purpose init is used.